# Known variables as unknowns in non-linear optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For the sake of simplicity in my non-linear optimization model, I have assumed that many known variables as unknown and then I provided its real value as constraint. I haven't modeled the problem completely yet, so I cannot compare results.

I'm using Ipopt which uses interior-point algorithm to solve the problem. Will it, in any chance ,affect my results? My concern is whether the constraint values is satisfied or approximated. Since I'm a beginner in optimization, the question might be too silly, so please forgive it.

Comment: It's quite likely that these values will not come out exactly to the desired values- how much variation can you live with?